# How to make a 00:00 timer in c#?

Tags: c#

I'm just trying to make a basic mm:ss timer for a little sports scoreboard.

I currently have

```
int i = 0;
private void matchTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    timeDisplay.Text = i.ToString("00:00");
}
```

But this fails because it doesn't account for minutes, so once time gets to 60, it just carries on

```
00:60
00:61
00:62
...
```

But I want it to be

```
01:00
01:01
01:02
...
```

and then stop at 80 minutes

Comment: add another variable to track minutes and when seconds get above 59, increase the minutes valirable and reset the seconds variable.

Comment: I am sure there is some built-in library for that, but you could also make some thoughts on it on your own. You would have to check for the amount of seconds and convert them into minutes.

Comment: yea a manual fix would be to count the minutes, but I kind of assumed there must be some easier way than that?

Answer (score 9):

You have more problems than you think. You're currently relying on the timer ticking *exactly* once per second. Don't do that - instead, use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to measure the elapsed time, and then update the display by formatting the value of [`Stopwatch.Elapsed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
timeDisplay.Text = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString("mm':'ss");
```

(See the [Custom TimeSpan format strings documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.)

Comment: I think for a second precision, it would be good enough to use `DateTime.Now`? Isn't a performance counter too much of a cannon?

Comment: @Georg: `Stopwatch` is specifically designed to measure elapsed time. The OP wants to measure elapsed time. Why use something of lower precision and error-prone (e.g. using `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow`!) when there's a type which does *exactly* what's required?

Comment: I get an error 'TimeSpan' does not contain a definition for 'Elapsed' and no extension method 'Elapsed' accepting a first argument of type 'Timespan' could be found

Comment: @oneman: That suggests you've got a variable called `stopwatch` of type `TimeSpan` instead of type `Stopwatch`...

Answer (score 1):

Timespan is made for that.

```
timeDisplay.Text = new TimeSpan(0, 0, i).ToString("mm\\:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is incorrect. You should create a [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) value and [format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) that.